# Python: Extract numbers from a string and put numbers into a list

Tags: python

I'm making this simple program to extract all of the numbers from a string and put them into a list. When I print it the output is: `[]`. Can someone help me?

```
new = []
def extract_nums(string):
    trash = []
    for x in string:
        if x.isalpha:
            trash.append(x)
        else:
            new.append(x)
extract_nums("hello 123")
print new
```

Comment: Given that you `print` **before** calling the function, *what on earth did you expect?!*

Comment: Just move the print to the next line without the new and it should work the way that you want.

Comment: That would be nice if you gave me an answer though because it should `print ['1' ,'2','3']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that `isalpha()` requires parentheses. Here is the code fixed:

```
new = []
def extract_nums(string):
    trash = []
    for x in string:
        if x.isalpha():  # added parentheses
            trash.append(x)
        else:
            new.append(x)

extract_nums("hello 123")
print(new)
```

A better idea altogether would be to use `isnumeric()` to extract the numbers like this:

```
new = []
def extract_nums(string):
    for x in string:
        if x.isnumeric():
            new.append(x)

extract_nums("hello 123")
print(new)
```

The reason the second is better is because the first would output whitespace and other characters that are not actually numbers. If you want just the numbers, use the second method.

Comment: I just tried to run it and said " isnumeric is not a thing".

Comment: maybe this could be a difference between python 2.x and 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have a list of strings, or convert them to numbers anyway? In that case, using `try` should be most elegant and solve both problems (I mean, remove everything that is not a number and convert it)

```
new = []
def extract_nums(string):
    for x in string:
        try:
            new.append(int(x))            
        except ValueError:
            continue

extract_nums("hello 123")
print(new)
```

I modified your code as little as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the right answer.

```
new = []
def extract_nums(string):
    trash = []
    for x in string:
        if x.isalpha():
            trash.append(x)
        elif x == ' ':
            trash.append(x)
        else:
            new.append(x)
extract_nums("hello 123")
print (new)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that characters such as @, #, $, {, etc. will still be in the list after the function has run. As far as using list comprehension, your answer doesn't use list comprehension either.